# Class 'Sentry\ClientBuilder' not found when trying to install Sentry

Tags: php, laravel, sentry

I am currently trying to add Sentry to my Laravel project but I got hit in this issue when I did 
`composer require sentry/sentry-laravel`.

The error I got hit with is:

```
@php artisan package:discover --ansi

   Error

  Class 'Sentry\ClientBuilder' not found

  at vendor/sentry/sentry-laravel/src/Sentry/Laravel/ServiceProvider.php:122
    118|                 ],
    119|                 $userConfig
    120|             );
    121|
  > 122|             $clientBuilder = ClientBuilder::create($options);
    123|
    124|             // Set the Laravel SDK identifier and version
    125|             $clientBuilder->setSdkIdentifier(Version::SDK_IDENTIFIER);
    126|             $clientBuilder->setSdkVersion(Version::SDK_VERSION);

  • Database name seems incorrect: You're using the default database name `homestead`. This database does not exist.

    Edit the `.env` file and use the correct database name in the `DB_DATABASE` key.
    https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#configuration
```

My .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Laravel version: 7.5.2

I am running everything throught Homestead and my database does exist and the project is running but I cannot figure out why do I get this error.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try with composer require sentry/sentry-laravel:1.7.0  (https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/laravel/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same errror.

Comment: That's odd. Do you have a folder vendor/sentry? If yes, delete it, run composer self-update then the composer require

Comment: Unfortunately, still no success

Answer (score 0):

use this `composer require sentry/sentry-laravel:1.7.0`

Since you’re using Laravel 7 the package will be auto-discovered in your

> config/app.php.

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately, I get the same error.

Comment: It looks like you might have previously ran composer install/update on PHP 7.3 or higher

Comment: Which version of PHP did you create your composer.lock. As an example, you probably might have created it with PHP version 5.6 and now upgrade to v7....Just guessing

Comment: I have created the composer.lock with v7. I have deleted the lock and made a fresh composer install to get a new lock but same issue

Answer (score 0):

@NinetyHH this is really weird, I think the database "tip" in unrelated, it tries to be smart and fails giving a confusing message :)

Can you add `"sentry/sentry-laravel": "^1.7"`, to your `composer.json` manually and running `composer update` to see if that resolves the issue, to me it looks like the dependency was not correctly installed.

If that doesn't fix it, can you:

- share your PHP version
- share your composer.json (so I can try and see if I can replicate it locally)
- share the full output of composer require sentry/sentry-laravel (so we can see what composer is doing)